# Find out who likes my website using the Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-like

Where can I find the details on who has liked and commented on my pages via the Facebook Like button that I've put on my website?

I recently put the Facebook Like plugin on my site and now see that there are a number of users that have clicked on the Like button.

> **Like**
>   John and 51 others like this.

Is there a way for me to see which Facebook users have clicked on the button?

I would like to see the comments and likes linked to this button.

Comment: Read the faq here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so, it is meant to be for your users to know about their friends. You could search for your site with `site:facebook.com` but not all profiles get crawled by Google.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Facebook documentation for the Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#faq), in the *FAQ* section. There you can find some options you can explore.

Answer (score 2):

suppose you want to record Likes in your database whenever a button is clicked:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

you would replace the alert() with your handling code.

Comment: What do you mean by "you would replace the alert() with your handling code" what is a handling code? thanks

Comment: He means you could write some JavaScript code to send data about the Like to your server. More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *showfaces* attribute to show profile pictures below the 'Like' button.
I've tested it on my posterous blog, and when used with the *standard* layout it does work :

```
<div class="posterous_fb_like_widget">{block:FbLike layout="standard" showfaces="true"  colorscheme="dark" /}</div>
```

result in :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Handling code, i basically the code that will notify you. You can create an ajax request that sends you an email, or saves this like in your database.

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer or give some examples of it's use?